# VBA macro failing after windows 10 switch

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a large macro, part of the code copies some cells to a chart object in order to save it as a .png and attach it to an email. After switching to windows 10, the chart object is empty. Oddly enough, if you add a breakpoint above the paste action, then resume the macro, everything works. This has me stumped. I've checked that the clipboard holds the table, and tried interrupting the code to replicate the breakpoint, nothing seems to work.

Edit:

this is the code that fails

```
Public Sub SaveTableRangeAs(ows As Worksheet, sFolderPath As String, sExtension As String, sRangeName As String)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht

    Set rng = ows.Range(sRangeName)
    rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

    Set cht = ows.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, rng.Width, rng.Height)
    'adding a breakpoint to line just below this one will result in the function working
    With cht
        .chart.Paste
        .chart.Export sFolderPath & sRangeName & "." & sExtension
        .Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to show us at least some of the code , to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: Try adding a DoEvents where you had put your break

Comment: I'm not sure how DoEvents work, the documentation I've found doesn't seem to match what is going on here. I've also added a timer to act as a sort of break and that didn't help